# JS AudioContext Interface: Am I doing this right?

Tags: javascript, audiocontext

I have the following function:

```
var PE_AudioManager_playSe = AudioManager.playSe;
AudioManager.playSe = function(se) {

    if (se.name.substring(0,5) === `data:`) {

        let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        let gainNode = audioContext.createGain();
        gainNode.gain.value = (se.volume / 100) || 0;

        let panNode = audioContext.createStereoPanner();
        panNode.pan.value = (se.pan / 100) || 0;

        let source = audioContext.createBufferSource();
        audioContext.decodeAudioData(se.name.split(`,`)[1].base64ToArrayBuffer(), function(buffer) {
            source.buffer = buffer;
            source.connect(gainNode);
            source.connect(panNode);
            source.connect(audioContext.destination);
            source.detune.value = (se.pitch - 100);
            source.start(0);
         });

    } else {

        PE_AudioManager_playSe.call(this,se);
    };

};
```

It is an alias for an existing function, that handles the playing of audio sound effects.  This alias "intercepts" the routine and uses the [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext) interface to play the sound if the source object's .name property is a data URI / base64 rather than a filename.

The sound effect plays without problem, except I don't think I am doing the panning (*.createStereoPanner*) or volume (*.createGain*) correctly- I don't think I hear a difference if I adjust the pan or volume.  But I could be wrong / crazy.

Does this code look correct?  Can anybody point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What information is used to justify “not correctly”? The precise problem/issue should be explained.

Comment: Thanks, @user2864740 . I don't think I can hear changes to the pan and/or volume.  I have expounded my question to reflect this.

Comment: And when using the original directly, does it function correctly? There are likely fiddle’s online that can be used as a live demo / reference.

Comment: @user2864740 the sound plays and I receive no errors.  I just don't think I can hear differences in the pitch or the volume when I test it, so I am asking... hoping there is somebody with *AudioContext* experience who can read my code and verify the logic is correct.  Where would I find these fiddles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Gain- and PannerNodes have min and max values. Control your input so that those ranges are honored. But the problem lies elsewhere.

```js
const ctx = new AudioContext();
const gainNode = ctx.createGain();
const panNode = ctx.createStereoPanner();

console.log(gainNode.gain.minValue, gainNode.gain.maxValue);
console.log(panNode.pan.minValue, panNode.pan.maxValue);
```

The connection of the nodes is critical. What helps for me is to look at it like it is a guitar (or any other electrical instrument) with wires that have to be connected. One wire goes from the guitar to the gain pedal, that wire goes to the pan pedal and that wire goes to the amp to output the signal.

Same goes for your nodes. Connect the `source` (guitar) to the `gainNode` (gain pedal) then the `gainNode` to the `panNode` (pan pedal) and the `panNode` to the `audioContext.destination` (the amp).

```
audioContext.decodeAudioData(se.name.split(`,`)[1].base64ToArrayBuffer(), function(buffer) {
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(panNode);
    panNode.connect(audioContext.destination);
    source.detune.value = (se.pitch - 100);
    source.start(0);
});
```

Really try to visualize it like that. Maybe even draw it on paper if you will make it more complex.

Multiple nodes can be connected to a single destination. Like having multiple sources which flow through the same effects to the destination. You can even make a switchboard out of this by connecting and disconnecting your nodes to and from different destinations, depending on what you need.

Hope this helps. If you have any question or I have been unclear, please let me know.